What can i++ see here?
Follow the symbols in two different ways...
→   ←   ↑   →   ↑   ↓
1   9   8  14  21  18

... and you will get the solution (1 word).
Hint 1:

 One way changes directions and the other way changes numbers.

Hint 2:

 A symbol is valid until its opposite symbol appears.


Welcome to Puzzling! Did you make this? Looks nice.

Thanks. Yes, I made this Puzzle.

Welcome to PSE (Puzzling Stack Exchange)!

The answer is

 ARROWS

1st letter

 (1 →) From the start if the alphabet (→) , take the 1st letter : A

2nd letter

 (21 ←) From the end of the alphabet (←) , take the 9th letter : R

3rd letter

 (8 ←↑) Still from the end of the alphabet (see hint 2) take the 8 + 1 (due to ↑) = 9th letter : R

4th letter

 (14 →↑) From the start of the alphabet, take the 14 + 1 = 15th letter : O

5th letter

 (21 →↑↑) From the start of the alphabet, take the 21 + 2 (apply ↑ twice) = 23rd letter : W

6th letter

 (18 →↑) One ↑ is canceled by ↓. From the start of the alphabet, take the 18 + 1 = 19th letter : S


That is absolutely correct. congratulations

@Ocean But what ++ means in the title?

In some programming languages, the “++” is an operator that increases a number. It should be a hint to increase and decrease the numbers.
